# Does reducing DPI scaling increase CPU usage?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface, dpi

I'm running a Surface Book, i5 with no dedicated GPU. I've just dropped the scaling further to 125%, by default it comes at 200%.

I've had a performance drop but it also coincided with Windows 10 Anniversary Edition. Task Manager shows around 30% when things aren't responding, but the Performance Manager can show 100% at the same time.

It's hard to get good data, because it's not responding. Just wondering if the DPI setting causes more work that's not shown due to more to render on screen.

Comment: Sounds like your CPU isn’t ramping up the frequency properly. In Resource Monitor, inspect the “% Maximum Frequency” indicator.

Comment: Got that going thanks @DanielB, what should I expect?

Comment: If it doesn’t reach 100%, your CPU isn’t using its full power. Task Manager multiplies CPU usage by “% Maximum Frequency”, so it only displays 100% when the CPU isn’t throttled.